# BitLocker Group Policy Requirements

Tags: bitlocker, group-policy

I am looking for help with creating a BitLocker policy through Group Policy.  I have failed doing this myself and need help from those more experienced than I am.

Server: Windows Server 2012
Clients: Windows 7 Ultimate & they are Dell Laptops (2014) with TPM modules

- Full local disk encryption
- **I want the boot up to be as simple as possible.  I don't want the Users to have to enter a PIN at start up.  The only protection I want is if the hard-drive is removed they won't be able to view the contents**
- Recovery keys should be stored in AD and manageable through there
- Any USB drive plugged into the laptop needs to be BitLocker encrypted before use and these can be PIN protected (4 digit numeric PIN)

**Is the above possible and can anyone help with the GPO settings**.

I followed a number of guides and deployed a Policy but I could see error messages stating my GPO had contradictory settings or a similar message.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing Keys in AD (make sure you've extended the schema - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875533(v=WS.10).aspx) - Windows Components/BitLocker Drive Encryption - Store BitLocker recovery information in Active Directory Domain Services (Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista) - Require Bitlocker backup to AD DS - Enabled, Choose appropriate we use Select BitLocker recovery information to store: Recovery passwords and key packages

For hard drives, you have settings specific to the OS and other Fixed hard drives.  Set both up as needed.  Choose how BitLocker-protected operating system drives can be recovered - Configure user storage of BitLocker recovery information: 
 Require 48-digit recovery password 
 Allow 256-bit recovery key 
Omit recovery options from the BitLocker setup wizard: Enabled 
Save BitLocker recovery information to AD DS for operating system drives: Enabled 
Configure storage of BitLocker recovery information to AD DS: Store recovery passwords and key packages 
Do not enable BitLocker until recovery information is stored to AD DS for operating system drives: Enabled

Removable Drives (USB) - Windows Components/BitLocker Drive Encryption/Removable Data Drives
Control use of Bitlocker on removable drives: Enabled
Deny write access to removable drives not protected by Bitlocker: Enabled
Allow users to suspend and decrypt BitLocker protection on removable data drives: Disabled
Choose how BitLocker-protected removable drives can be recovered -
Save BitLocker recovery information to AD DS for removable data drives: Enabled 
Configure storage of BitLocker recovery information to AD DS: Backup recovery passwords and key packages
Configure use of passwords for removable data drives (no PIN, but you can make the password 4 characters with complexity disabled, we don't): Enabled
Configure password complexity for removable data drives: Allow password complexity 
Minimum password length for removable data drive: 8

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will not get to test this fully now as I am no longer involved.  I appreciate your answer very much and have up-ticked it